# Are CIM/XML and RDF/XML completely different?

Tags: xml, rdf, cim

I am studying RDF and CIM.
I am studying RDF after reading IEC 61970 501 and 552, but I am not sure what exactly is the difference between these.
From what I have understood so far, is it right to define namespace well to become CIM XML?

Comment: All RDF/XML and CIM/XML have in common that it's XML - nothing more, nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IEC 61970-552:2016 specifies the format and rules for exchanging
> modelling information based upon the CIM. It uses the CIM RDF Schema
> presented in IEC 61970-501 as the meta-model framework for
> constructing XML documents of power system modelling information. The
> style of these documents is called. CIMXML format [IEC 61970-552:2016](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/25939)

> RDF/XML is a syntax, defined by the W3C, to express an RDF graph
> (triples) as an XML document. [An XML Syntax for RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax)

In plain language RDF/XML tells you how to serialize triples (RDF graph) as an XML document, where other option might be a Turtle serialization. And the CIMXML tells you how to serialize CIM modeled data as XML messages. It is based on CIM/RDFS but further more expands on that concept.

I hope that this will give you a clear picture, but feel free to reach out if you have more questions.

Comment: I don't see the difference between RDF/XML of W3C and CIM RDF XML. Are they both syntactically the same?

Comment: RDF/XML is just a syntax.
CIMXML is a format of message exchange.

As @UninformedUser pointed out they have XML in common, but they are just completely different things and should not be compared to say at least.

Comment: Then, is the RDF schema of W3C and the CIM RDF schema of 501 also just syntax?

Comment: Yes, triples serialized to RDF/XML format would look familiar if put next to CIMXML message, as they are both syntactically written in XML, but that's all there is. CIM is a domain oriented model of data, with a specific purpose, and CIMXML is and industry grade specification, with a communication intent set in its design.

Comment: Short answer, no. RDFS is an ontology language, used to represent certain knowledge, to describe a domain. CIM RDFS is a standard that defines how you express CIM model as an RDFS ontology, where as a remainder CIM model is described in UML language.